# save file with JFileChooser save dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have written a Java program that opens all kind of files with a JFileChooser. Then I want to save it in another directory with the JFileChooser save dialog, but it only saves an empty file. What can I do for saving part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

JFileChooser just returns the File object, you'll have to open a FileWriter and actually write the contents to it.

E.g.

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
   fw.write(contents);
   // etc...
}
```

Edit:

Assuming that you simply have a source file and destination file and want to copy the contents between the two, I'd recommend using something like [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache's [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to do the heavy lifting.

E.g.

```
FileUtils.copy(source, dest);
```

Done!

Comment: contents is whatever you want to write to the file

Comment: but I thought the computer would do everything for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to [Kris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377703/save-file-with-jfilechooser-save-dialog/2377715#2377715) - I guess, you didn't read the contents of the file yet. Basically you have to do the following to copy a file with java and using JFileChooser:

1. Select the **source** file with the FileChooser. This returns a File object, more or less a wrapper class for the file's filename
2. Use a FileReader with the File to get the contents. Store it in a String or a byte array or something else
3. Select the **target** file with the FileChooser. This again returns a File object
4. Use a FileWriter with the target File to store the String or byte array from above to that file.

The File Open Dialog does not read the contents of the file into memory - it just returns an object, that represents the file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like..

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
String textToSave = mainTextPane.getText();
BufferedWriter writer = null;

try
{
writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(file));
writer.write(textToSave);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message saved. (" + file.getName()+")",
"ImPhil HTML Editer - Page Saved",
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
catch  (IOException e)
{ }
```

Comment: Link to "full example" is 404.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for flagging this up. I have updated the link for you.