# JFileChooser - Custom file name (create new file)

Tags: java, swing, file-io, save, jfilechooser

I may be missing something obvious in the `JFileChooser` API, but when I try and use a `JFileChooser` to save a file, I can only select pre-existing files to save to, not enter a new name and save to that. Is that even possible with a `JFileChooser` or should I be using a different API?

I have this code to try and do what I'm attempting:

```
public static File getUserFile() {      
    final SaveFileChooser fc = new SaveFileChooser();

    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    for(FileFilter ch : FileFilterUtils.getAllFilters()) {
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(ch);
    }       

    int option = fc.showSaveDialog(JPad.getFrame());

    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return fc.getSelectedFile();
    } 
    return null;
}

public static class SaveFileChooser extends JFileChooser {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8175471295012368922L;

    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        File f = getSelectedFile();
        if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG){
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JPad.getFrame(), "The file exists, overwrite?", "Existing file", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

            switch(result){
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                super.approveSelection();
                return;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                cancelSelection();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377703/save-file-with-jfilechooser-save-dialog) post and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401285/save-using-jfilechooser-with-pre-populated-file-name?rq=1)

Comment: There is an example made by oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `if` condition:

```
if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG)
```

What happens if `f` doesn't exist (which is what you would like to be possible)?

You could try:

```
if(getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG) {
    if(f.exists()) {
        // your overwrite checking
    } else {
        super.approveSelection();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    File file = null;
    String path = "";
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFileFilter());
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        path = file.getPath();

        repaint();

    }

}                                        

class ImageFileFilter extends FileFilter {

    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return false; //or ur code what file u want to return
        }}
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution a little more? It is not a SSCCE and I don't see the relation with the original code...

Comment: i am new to  java i created an application in netbeans to browse files to save and i tried this code which lets me to create a new folder also so i suggested this code :) if it can help if not i am really sorry

Comment: this will not work, it should invoke `showSaveDialog` or the user will not have any ability to type in a new file name