# Throw a file to the user

Tags: java, spring, file-handling

I'm using data handling

```
  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(file_name);
  workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
```

After the code runs the file is saved somewhere in the system without any indication. I want that the file should be available to user as a pop up when we download anything of the internet and the user can save the file wherever they want.

Comment: Then you should simply open a file dialog to ask the user for the location the file should be written to.

Comment: that's what i'm asking for. how to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [save file with JFileChooser save dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377703/save-file-with-jfilechooser-save-dialog)

Comment: not a duplicate, nor a  solution

Comment: It is a solution to downoload/save your file as isnot2bad suggested above. If that isn't what you want you need to make your question clearer or it will be closed. That's a pop up file chooser, that in conjunction with the FileWriter will allow the user to save a file. Rather than saying it's not a solution explain further what you want.

Comment: the user should be able to save the file wherever they want. my code quietly saves the file to whatever "file_name" is replaced with.

Comment: Ok... so they use the JFileChooser and set where to save the file. I don't think there's enough information here to be sure to be honest. That thread, and JFileChooser allow you to save a file to any directory like any other file you would 'Save As' or download.. What EXACTLY is the issue here?   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to get outputstream from response and write whole file in that stream. refer to [example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-sample-application-for-downloading-files) for more detail